# Is it possible to be a provider for the Windows Phone 8 Photo Chooser? If so, how?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8

The company I work for has an online storage backup and synchronization solution. We'd like to integrate with Windows Phone 8 for our app and allow users to pick from their existing online photos in when they want to get photos from the Photo Chooser for use in other apps, for editing, or for sharing. I see that I am able to pick from Facebook photo albums (after installing their app) and from SkyDrive photos along with photos that I have on the camera roll or saved on the phone.

Is there a way to become a provider for the Photo Chooser? See this photo (https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=151B84C1DD698071!553&authkey=!ABD9ljtF6553ZS4) as an example of what I mean.

I can't seem to find anything in the documentation on MSDN or elsewhere for this. Would also like to show up under the Photos Hub as an album just like Facebook and SkyDrive do. Are these locked down and only made available to select partner apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: there's no way to way to implement your mock up in WP8. WP8 doesn't have the same picker extensiblity as Win8 apps have.

Long answer:

WP8 does introduce a new concept known as "Auto upload photos apps". This new type of app can be enabled from the user's settings menu to automatically upload camera photos online. Since the actual settings screen shown will be part of your app, I don't see why you wouldn't ask permission and also use that time to also download photos from an online cloud storage to the phone.

You can Read more about these type of apps @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj571205(v=vs.105).aspx

You can use the MediaLibrary methods to add pictures to the [local camera roll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769549%28VS.92%29.aspx) or [photo albums](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.savepicture.aspx).

The way this type of app works is that it gets a ResourceIntensive BackgroundAgent that once chosen from the Settings menu will not require user interaction. That's important since normally all types of scheduled tasks will be removed after 14 days of the user not using the app. That doesn't apply to auto upload photo apps.

[ResourceIntensiveBackgroundAgents have a few limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_ConstraintsforResourceintensiveAgents) including: they only run when the phone is connected to battery, when WiFi is available and they've got up to 10 minutes to complete execution. Auto upload photos apps need to work under those limitations.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done it myself but from the documentation I would say Photos_Extra_Hub is the extension you are looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202966(v=vs.105).aspx

Here a howto

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Extending_the_Windows_Phone_Pictures_Hub

### I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but those don't indicate any points of extensibility for what I'm looking for (becoming a provider for the Photo Chooser). Must not be possible at this time. Seems weird they wouldn't allow extensibility to get at photos from other locations since they allow grabbing from SkyDrive and from Facebook.